# How to use switch case with multiple variables

Tags: flutter, switch-statement

I am trying to check for two vars in a switch case statement, but I don't know how. something like this:

```
switch (FABvisible && settingDate) {
case (true, true):
  break;
case (true, false):
  break;
case (false, true):
  break;
case (false, false):
  break;
default:
```

}

but the condition in the case statement gives me error, can someone tell me if this is possible somehow?

Comment: on switch case you can use only one variable but if multiple why dont if else? statement

Comment: Ok thanks @ArbiterChil , I just wanted to know if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

I try this one

```
bool fABvisible = false;
 bool settingDate= true;
  switch ([fABvisible , settingDate]) {
case ([true, true]):
      print("FABvisible = true , settingDate = true");
  break;
case ([true, false]):
      print("FABvisible = true , settingDate = false");
  break;
case ([false, true]):
      print("FABvisible = false , settingDate = true");
  break;
case ([false, false]):
      print("FABvisible = false , settingDate = false");
  break;
default:
  }
```

result:
"FABvisible = false , settingDate = true"